# Windows xp not resolving entries en etc/hosts with DNSClient started

Tags: services, windows-xp

We have a very strange problem on a newly installed Windows XP machine. For some reason when DNSClient service is running, it wont resolve any entries in the windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts file. When its turned off it resolves them, but then the service locator lookups we do for EJB's takes to long and it times out. Is there any way we could have the DNSClient running and have it resolve host file entries?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the filename should be "hosts" ?
Here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727005.aspx is some ideas abuot flushing the dns cache etc

Comment: misspelt, it is hosts.